# RxJava block stream until other observer finish

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am getting a Flowable from one method called `getAlldata()` 
and this method will get the data from the server and then modify the data that been returned base on the data that had been stored in the DB.

So the process of this method goes like this:

1. getdata from the server
2. doOnNext for each item get the id
3. get the local data by id.
4. modify the current item

**The problem is:**

the result will be return before actully the modification of the data in `doOnNext()` since getting the local data from the DB is another observable.

**Question**

how can I delay stream until the other observable that is on `doOnNext()` completes?

**The codes**

```
   private Flowable<List<MyModule>> getAlldata() {
         return remoteDataSource
                            .getData().flatMap(data -> Flowable.fromIterable(data))
                            .doOnNext(new Consumer<MyModule>() {
                                @Override
                                public void accept(MyModule singleItem) throws Exception {
                                    localDataSource.getData(singleItem.getId())
                                    .firstElement().toFlowable()
                                    .subscribe(new Consumer<Optional<MyModule>>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void accept(Optional<MyModule> itemOptional) throws Exception {
                                            if (itemOptional.isPresent()) {
                                               // modify the item
                                            }

                                        }
                                    });


                                }
                            })
                            .distinct()
                            .sorted(ProductsRepository.this::sortItems)
                            .toList().toFlowable();
    }
```

Comment: you need to map each of your api response with doOnNext right

Comment: yes, for each one of items.

Answer (score 0):

Use flatmap operator instead of `doOnNext()` which get the singleItem as a parameter and throw an observable of the type localdatabase. so now you can map the response instead of making your Observable wait.

```
Observable<ModuleData> obs = remoteDataSource
         .getData().flatMapIterable(data ->data)
         .flatMap(singleItem->localDataSource.getData(singleItem.getId()))
          .distinct()
          .sorted(ProductsRepository.this::sortItems)
          .toList().toFlowable();
```

Comment: thank you but it is still not clear ?
Cannot resolve method 'zipWith(io.reactivex.Flowable<com.google.common..base.Optional<MyModule>>, <lambda expression>)

and how to get the singleItem ? in order to get the id.

Comment: Check if zip has any overload to receive item

Comment: base on my understanding zipwith should take ether 
Iterable or Publisher?
so the issue is what goes into zipWith() ?

Comment: but why it is giving this error 
Cannot resolve method 'zipWith(io.reactivex.Flowable<com.google.common..base.Optio‌​nal<MyModule>>, <lambda expression>)

Comment: but I don`t want to return the localdatabase type since the local database return Optional<MyModule> and I want to return Flowable<List<MyModule>>
.

Comment: maybe you did not get what I want.

the server returns a list of MyModule 
and the local return single MyModule

Comment: add  .firstElement().toFlowable() to getId() forgot to add that to the answer

Comment: and I want to modify each MyModule that comes from the server with the MyModule  from  local

Comment: you can do that after flatmap operator using map operator

Comment: map operator will only give one MyModule 
where I need two of them the one from the server and the local one.

Comment: so what is the correct implementation?
just give me some hints?